# Craft Commerce 2.0.2 Shipping Rule Names & Descriptions—How?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I just noticed I had to update some templates after updating to the latest Commerce version (2.0.2).

How does one go about getting the method's rule description?

I currently have it set up to apply a rule based on geographical shipping location (like contiguous US states / Hawaii and Alaska / Russia / World / Oceania)—but `{{ method.description }}` from within `{% for handle, method in cart.availableShippingMethods %}` breaks the site.

Cheers!

Comment: I would also want to display the rule name together with description. Right now it only displays the method name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

calling

```
{% set methods = cart.availableShippingMethods %}
```

which is the same as calling:

```
{% set methods = craft.commerce.shippingMethods.getAvailableShippingMethods(cart) %}
```

the above returns an array of shipping method models, keyed by the shipping method handle.

to get the matching rule for each available method

```
{% for method in methods %}
{% set rule = method.getMatchingShippingRule(cart) %}
{% set price = method.getPriceForOrder(cart) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You <s>have to</s> can loop through the shipping rules for the shipping method.

```
{% for handle, method in cart.availableShippingMethods %}

  {% if method.shippingRules|length %}
    {% for shippingRule in method.shippingRules %}
      {{ shippingRule.name }}
      {{ shippingRule.description }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```